# Set prototype for all object properties

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the object:

```
var Animals = {
  cow: {
    id: 1,
    value: "moo"
  },
  chicken: {
    id: 2,
    value: "cluck"
  }
};
```

What I'd like to do override the toString method on all the properties (cow, chicken, etc.).  I know I can do it individually, but is there something to cover all properties in one call?  Something like:

```
Animals.properties.prototype.toString = function() {
  return this.value;
}
```

Comment: If you create your animal instances from a common Animal prototype using constructor functions you xould : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you can do is iterate over the object's properties:

```
for (var prop in Animals) {
    Animals[prop].toString = ...;
}
```